# How to add onclick event to string rendered button in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

```
<div onClick={(event) => this.addToCart(event)}>
  <ReactMarkdownWithHtml children={this.props.customButton} allowDangerousHtml />
</div>
```

I have situation like in the code. I'm rendering button and I want to add on click event on that rendered button. `this.props.customButton has value '<button>Test</button>'`. Obviously this is not a good way to add onClick event to rendered button. I'm get the button in my app, but when I click on button my program fails. Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `React.cloneElement` to create a new button from the existing one with the added `onClick` handler, then pass it to `ReactMarkdownWithHtml`.

```js
render() {
    const handleClick = (event) => this.addToCart(event)
    const buttonWithClickHandler = React.cloneElement(this.props.customButton, { onClick: handleClick }

    return (
        <ReactMarkdownWithHtml children={buttonWithClickHandler} allowDangerousHtml />
    )
}
```